# Getting unique enteries from the file

Tags: java, collections

I am parsing a file with more than 4M lines in it. It is of the form a^b^c^d^...^....
 Now i want all the unique points(only the 1st two entries should be unique) from the file. So what I do is,

```
String str;
Set<String> lines = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
Set<String> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(lines);
String str1[] = str.split("\\^");
set.add(str1[0]+"^"+str1[1]);
```

So this gives me the unique 1st and 2nd unique points from the file. However,  I also want the 3rd point(timestamp) i.e str1[2] associated with the above points. The new file should be of the form.

```
  str1[0]^str1[1]^str1[2]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I think you need to clarify; if you have the combinations `1^2^3` and `1^2^4` the first two would match, but which timestamp would you want?

Comment: I would like to have the timestamp that came first i.e 1^2^3.

Comment: Where is the timestamp in 1^2^3?

Comment: The 3rd entry is the timestamp. In 1^2^3, 3 is the timestamp and it should co-relate to the 1st two entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class containing the information you need which you will store in the set, but only care about the first two in equals/hashCode. Then you can do:

```
Set<Point> set = new HashSet<Point>();
String str1[] = str.split("\\^");
set.add(new Point(str1[0], str1[1], str1[2]));
```

Using:

```
public class Point {

    String str1;
    String str2;
    String str3;

    public Point(String str1, String str2, String str3) {
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str2 = str2;
        this.str3 = str3;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((str1 == null) ? 0 : str1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((str2 == null) ? 0 : str2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (str1 == null) {
            if (other.str1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!str1.equals(other.str1))
            return false;
        if (str2 == null) {
            if (other.str2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!str2.equals(other.str2))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the rather verbose equals and hashCode, I was having Eclipse generate them for me

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions that come to mind.

1. Make a class for the 3 entries.
   Override the equals method and only check on the first 2 entries there, so 2 objects are equal if the first 2 entries are equal. Now add all the items to the set.
   So what you 'll get in your set is a list with unique first and second points and the first occaurance of your timestamp.
2. Another solution is to keep two lists, one with your 2 points + time stamp, one with only your 2 points. 
   The you can do set.contains(...) to check if you already saw the point and if you didn't add to the list with 2 points + timestamp.

Comment: Make sure you have proper implementation of both equals and hashCode, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: @Nactive I thought about the 2nd solution and found it a bit clumsy and thought if there was a smarter way.

Comment: Ofc the first implementation is better then the second one. But the second one is just easier and since you already use set.add(str1[0]+"^"+str1[1]) to add unique 'points' I thought you might be interested in a fast way instead of defining a new class and stuff like that.